# How to get Uri from Bitmap (Lollipop)

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, android-bitmap

Ok, I tried this code:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

and looks like it can't do the job. When I log it it prints:

```
content://media/external/images/media/25756
```

which doesn't helps me because I need it for `new File(Uri)`. Strangely, getImageUri method returns Uri, but File doesn't seem to recognize it. Anyone has method to retrieve Uri from freshly made bitmap?

P.S. As far as I read, it doesn't work since KitKat.

**edit**
This code works and from this I want to retrieve Uri:

```
                croppedBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
                cropImageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);


       Button crop = ...;
       crop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cropContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Bitmap croppedImage = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);
                paramsContener.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and looks like it can't do the job

That would depend upon what "the job" is.

> When I log it it prints: `content://media/external/images/media/25756` which doesn't helps me because I need it for new File(Uri)

First, if you want to save a bitmap to a file, use a `FileOutputStream` rather than a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Java file I/O has been around for ~20 years.

Second, if you are expecting to get file paths from a `ContentProvider` like `MediaStore`, you are going to be disappointed. You get back a `Uri`, like the `content://` one in your question. [A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to read in the data identified by that `Uri`. The concept of a "URI" representing an opaque handle to something you get via a stream has been around at least as long as has HTTP, which has been around for ~25 years.

> Strangely, getImageUri method returns Uri, but File doesn't seem to recognize it.

That is because a `Uri` is not a file.

Comment: I based on android documentation, where constructors where taking Uri and String as arguments. I updated my question to explain from what bitmap I want to take Uri.

Comment: @jeand'arme: "This code works and from this I want to retrieve Uri" -- you already have the `Uri`. It is the second parameter to your `getBitmap()` call. If you mean that you want to get some sort of cropped output out of that `CropImageView`, and it returns a `Bitmap`, and you want a `File` to point to that `Bitmap`, then use `compress()` to write it to a `FileOutputStream` to write the `Bitmap` to the `File`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add the missing puzzle which is `Bitmap croppedImage = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();` and from that I want to obtain it. That's why that Uri from second argument won't do the job.

Comment: @jeand'arme: OK, so, as I wrote, if you want a file to contain that `Bitmap`, use `compress()` to write it to a `FileOutputStream`. Your first code snippet in your sample hands the `Bitmap` over to `MediaStore`, which is welcome to put the image wherever it wants to, including places (like removable storage) that you can't access. You seem insistent that you want a `File`; if so, you have to write the file yourself to a location that you can access. Then, perhaps use `MediaScannerConnection` to get that image indexed in `the `MediaStore`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it thanks to @CommonsWare - made something like this. Hope will help it another people as well:

```
public String makeBitmapPath(Bitmap bmp){
        // TimeStamp
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, "Photo"+ timeStamp +".jpg"); // the File to save to
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
        } catch (IOException e){
            // whatever
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }
```